# Change the class of the first div inside a XSLT foreach loop

Tags: xml, xslt

I am fairly new to XSLT. This is my XSLT code:

```
<xsl:for-each select="/page/articles[@controlid='name']/article[position() &lt; 10]/article_data">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">
        <xsl:if test="/page/articles[@controlid='name']/article[position() = 1]">
          <xsl:attribute name="class">
            <xsl:text>col-md-8 col-xs-12</xsl:text> 
          </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:if>
    ....HTML markup.....
    </div>
</xsl:for-each>
```

I am creating a bootstrap layout with a for-each loop.
And I am trying to change the class of the first `div` from 'col-md-4' to 'col-md-8', but the above code changes the classes of all 10 `div`s.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide the relevant part of the XML so that there's a [mcve]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
<xsl:for-each select="/page/articles[@controlid='name']/article[position() &lt; 10]/article_data">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">
        <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
          <xsl:attribute name="class">col-md-8 col-xs-12</xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:if>
    ....HTML markup.....
    </div>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Untested, because no code to allow testing was provided.

Comment: That will do. Thanks